# Call a function within a Call to a function

Tags: javascript, function

Whats the best practice for calling a function inside of a call to another function on the same line?

Here's my example, but it looks sloppy

```
<script>
function someFunction (a,b,c) { ... }
function otherFunction (d) { ... }
</script>
<a href="place.html" onClick="someFunction(varOne, varTwo, otherFunction(varThree))">a link</a>
```

Comment: Pass the argument and call the other function in the function body ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call directly into inline

```
function function_one() {
        alert("The function called 'function_one' has been called.");
    }

    function function_two() {
        alert("The function called 'function_two' has been called.");
    }

    <a href="place.html" onClick="function_one(),function_two">a link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it that way

```
<script>
function someFunction (a,b,c) { 
...
otherFunction(c);
... }
function otherFunction (d) { ... }
</script>
<a href="place.html" onClick="someFunction(varOne, varTwo, varThree)">a link</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Inline handlers are essentially `eval` inside HTML markup and result in hard to read, hard to manage code. Attach them properly using Javascript instead, and assign the first result to a variable first:

```
<script>
function someFunction (a,b,c) { ... }
function otherFunction (d) { ... }
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded, () => {
  const a = document.querySelector('#placeAnchor');
  a.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const otherResult = otherFunction(varThree);
    someFunction(varOne, varTwo, otherResult);
  });
});
</script>

<a href="place.html" id="placeAnchor">a link</a>
```